# Office 365 api loses stored settings when removing and readding the app in word online

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-apps

I am developing a Office 365 application using the O365 API and noticed some weird behavior when saving settings using document.context.settings.saveAsync()

When creating a new document in Office 365 using Word online, when adding an App that saves something in the document.settings, even after doing saveAsync, if you close the application and readd it again, it will loose the saved settings.

Everything works fine if you open an existing Document and do the same steps.

Is that the expected behavior, or is that a bug?
Where can i report this kind of bugs of the Office 365 API?

Answer (score 0):

After we create the document online, the document was saved automatically. This **saveAsync** works well for both exiting document and the new document.

To narrow this issue, I suggest that you make sure the method **Settings.saveAsyn** save successfully. We can use code below to determine the success or failure of the operation and show the settings:

```
 function showSettings() {
    var val = Office.context.document.settings.get('mySetting');
    app.showNotification("mySetting",val);
}

function saveSettings() {
    Office.context.document.settings.set('mySetting', 'mySetting value');
    Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync(function (AsyncResult) {
        app.showNotification("Settings Save", AsyncResult.status)
    })
}
```